# Decomposition based on approximate separators in graph

Tags: graph-theory, co.combinatorics, treewidth

Suppose I want to find vertex subset $S$ of graph $G=(V,E)$ such that any simple closed walk that visits vertices both in $S$ and in $V\backslash S$ has length $\ge g$

The idea is to relax requirements of tree decomposition to get bag-graph of large girth instead of a tree, and form an approximation algorithm based on this decomposition.

Does this come up in any literature?

**Clarification**
Bags in the [context of](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_decomposition) tree decomposition are sets of nodes. Taking bags produced by tree decomposition algorithm and connecting any pair of bags that are not disjoint gives a tree.

This trade-off idea is briefly mentioned in Koller's "Graphical Models" book where she calls it "Cluster Graph" and defines it similar to a tree decomposition except that the graph formed by connecting overlapping bags is not restricted to be a tree. In the context of probabilistic inference, this approach gives a way to trade off cost and accuracy, with exact tree decomposition-based approach as a special case.

Since quality of approximation improves with girth of such graph while complexity increases with size of bags/clusters, a natural question is when it's possible to find a "(relaxed?) tree decomposition" where largest bag size is bounded above and girth is bounded below

Comment: what's a bag graph ?

Comment: @Suresh : I think by bag-graph Yaroslav means the underlying tree, in the case of a tree decomposition. In his modified decomposition (of whose exact definition I am not sure) this may not necessarily be a tree (I guess), so he calls it a bag-graph.

Comment: added clarification

Comment: It seems to me that your approximation question is a bit of a red herring: the real interesting question is whether there's a nice notion of the 'cycle width" of a graph (or "girth width" or something like that)

Comment: For every k you could define "girth width" as the largest achievable girth of the "modified tree decomposition" such that each bag is smaller than k.

Comment: right. doesn't seem like anything is known about this

Comment: Related post on MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/48197/the-girthwidth-of-a-graph